# how do i make an admin grid based on sales_order table (some columns but not all) using best practice?

Tags: admin, grid, sql, best-practice, table

### Let's say I need an **admin grid**
where not all columns of the `sales_order` table will be,
but only some of them. For example:

1. customer_id
2. customer_name
3. nickname

---

**How best to solve such a problem?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make Grid for just Practice:

You should follow these steps:

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html#step-5-method-1---create-admin-grid-using-component

OR You can Override the sales grid and customize it.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that we establish a connection with the table in di.xml, and then we get the data in the layout file by specifying the fields of the same name?

Comment: Yes.  You can try this.

Comment: If this helps you a little bit, Then you can mark this an answer

Comment: dear friend, could you write step by step instructions in short form for this? I would be very happy for help! :)

Comment: You will follow these :
Create new module 
Use Core Database Table
Override the Grid
Add Columns you want and then save it in the db